# ¿Cómo saber que botón ha sido pulsado? React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Tengo dos botones tal que así:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(true)} style={stylesDropDown.acceptButton}>
                        <Text> Aceptar </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(true)} style=stylesDropDown.refuseButton}>
                        <Text> Rechazar </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Yo quiero que cuando se ejecute la función 'setModalVisible' saber que botón de estos dos ha sido pulsado. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil es mandar un indicador en los parámetros de la función. Bien puede ser que modifiques tu función `setModalVisible` o bien que crees una nueva función intermedia:

```
notifyModalVisibleChange(from, visible) {
    console.log(from); // btn-X
    this.setModalVisible(visible);
}

...

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.notifyModalVisibleChange("btn-A", true)}
                  style={stylesDropDown.acceptButton}>
                        <Text> Aceptar </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.notifyModalVisibleChange("btn-B", true)}
                  style=stylesDropDown.refuseButton}>
                        <Text> Rechazar </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```